# Weblogic Webservices - In SOAP response - GT resolves to left bracket but LT does not (stays as &lt;)?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, weblogic

I have a Webservice that returns an XML Payload.

In that Web Service Response - My GT brackets resolve to a real bracket - while the LT stays as `&lt;` - i have no idea why.

Using

Weblogic 10.3

The Webservice is annotated as

```java
@WebService(name = "MyService", portName = "MyServicePort", serviceName = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://kwikksilva/myservice/ws")
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
```

The method like so

```java
@WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "SyncResponse", targetNamespace = "http://kwikksilva/myservice/ws")
    public SyncResponseTO processRequest(
```

It returns a TO with a payload

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "SyncResponse", namespace = "http://kwikksilva/myservice/ws")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SyncResponseTO implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The response. */
    @XmlElement(name = "Payload", nillable = false, required = true)
    private String payload;
```

I get a response back which looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:processSyncRequestResponse xmlns:ns2="http://kwikksilva/myservice/ws">
                <ns2:SyncResponse>
                    <Payload xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">
                        &lt;Vbc>
                            &lt;ApptEffDt>795243600000&lt;/ApptEffDt>
                        &lt;/Vbc>
                </Payload>
                </ns2:SyncResponse>
            </ns2:processSyncRequestResponse>
        </S:Body>
    </S:Envelope>
```

Why would one encode to a bracket and not the other?

Has anyone got any ideas on this - i am confused....

Comment: Do you have any message handlers or filters that could modify the payload?

Comment: None at all - we've added some handlers which show us the payload prior to return - and we can see the issue there aswell.

Comment: your `Payload` node is shown to return string, not a complex type, is it what you intended?

Comment: Well - the payload is normally XML - but i think we thought it would make sense to leave it as string - as the payload *could* be anything (i.e FLat File records from a mainframe) and we could wrap them in CDATA. Does that make sense?

Comment: If i get you right, you're trying to send xml as string inside soap payload. Then I have no idea why server does not escape GT, may be it's because it thinks that escaping LT is enough to consider this node as `xs:string`, but you could easily escape GT manually in your code - String's `replaceAll` will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah i think we might have to - will update if we find another way.

Answer (score 0):

take the payload and xml decode it.  It should solve the problem.